# Dynamic provisioners from variables in module

Tags: terraform

I've just learned some basics about Terraform and created simple reusable Terraform module with AWS EC2 isntance and some additional resources (security groups, ellastic ip, ssh key-pairs etc), it's available on https://github.com/g4s8/docker-worker

Now I want to copy local files to EC2 instance on create (I gues using [file provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/file.html)). Is it possible to define files variable like this:

```
module "worker" {
  # ...
  files = [
    {
      src: "./file1",
      dst: "/home/ec2-user/file1"
    },
    {
      src: "./file2",
      dst: "/home/ec2-user/file2"
    }
  ]
}
```

and create dynamic provisioners based on these variables:

```
resource "aws_instance" "worker" {
  # pseudocode:
  # for (file : var.files) {
      provisioner "file" {
        source = file.source
        destination = file.destination
      }
  # } 
}
```

So my question: is it possible to dynamically generate provisioners in module, if yes how can I implement iterating over all items of files to create it? I didn't find some references in [input variable documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html) about it.

Comment: This feature (`for_each`) is in terraform v0.12.x, which is still in beta version. You can have a try :   https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/hashicorp-terraform-0-12-preview-for-and-for-each

Comment: Dynamic provisioners are not possible even in Terraform v0.12, because Terraform processes them early during graph preparation rather than during the graph walk where expressions can be resolved. Currently the best way to solve this problem is to put both of these files in a common parent directory and upload the whole directory at once.

Comment: @MartinAtkins Thanks to clarify